# How do I get a 0 sum when grouping by more than one field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tried looking and found using left outer joins tends to be the answer, but that usually is for a sum to a date grouping and not 2 levels of groupings. I think the additional grouping is messing me up.

My Table:

dbo._Labour

_id int pk  --the id of this labour entry 
_date date  --the date of this entry (using this to group by year)
_activityid int  --what type of activity they are doing
_typeid int   --3 possible options (0,1,2) of what type of item they are performing the activity on
_hours numeric(4,0)  --how many hours were spent performing that activity.

My ultimate goal is to know for each year the total hours spent working for each of the 3 types (0,1,2). My current code:

```
select coalesce(SUM(_hours),0) as _hours, YEAR(_date) as _year, l._typeid 
from RelayTanks.dbo._Labour l 
left outer join (select YEAR(_date) as _y 
from RelayTanks.dbo._Labour group by YEAR(_date)) y on y._y = YEAR(l._date) 
where _activityid in (3,4,9,11) 
group by YEAR(_date), l._typeid 
order by year(_date), l._typeid'
```

which results in:

```
_typeid _year   _hours
0   2015    1174
1   2015    3953
2   2015    851
0   2016    119
1   2016    541
2   2016    65
1   2017    10
```

What I am looking for is 2017 to show _hours 0 for _typeid 0 and a 0 for _typeid 2. ie:

```
_typeid _year   _hours
0   2015    1174
1   2015    3953
2   2015    851
0   2016    119
1   2016    541
2   2016    65
0   2017    0    
1   2017    10
2   2017    0
```

I have tried many things including 2 outer left joins and I just can't quite figure it out. The current out join I thought would be a good substitute to actually having a dummy year table and only showing years where at least some work has been done.

This is my first question posted here so many apologies if I have neglected to include some info or am missing some community etiquette.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: cross join your typeid list with the year list then left join to that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would get you there, assuming that all of the possible years and types are already represented in your data:

```
SELECT year(_date), _typeid, _hours = SUM(_hours)
FROM _Labour
GROUP BY year(_date), _typeid
UNION
SELECT year(y._date), t._typeid, 0
FROM _Labour y, _Labour t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM _Labour WHERE year(_Labour._date) = year(y._date) AND _Labour._typeid = t._typeid)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to do this with just one table then something like this might work.

```
SELECT  s._typeid,
        s._y,
        coalesce(SUM(lj._hours),0) as _hours
FROM
(   
    SELECT t._typeid, y._y
    FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT _typeid FROM RelayTanks.dbo._Labour) t
            CROSS JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(_date) _y FROM RelayTanks.dbo._Labour) y
) s
LEFT JOIN RelayTanks.dbo._Labour lj ON lj._typeid = s._typeid AND YEAR(lj._date) = s._y
```

performance might be terrible.. you might want to consider adding a computed column for the _date.year value

Comment: Thank you, both of these answers worked. Your answer seemed very comprehensive, I selected @Bob-S because it was easier to understand for me. Both are great learning opportunities for me and I thank you.

Comment: @enfrost no problem.. not a big fan of old style cartesian joins but if that makes more since you can do this.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10b3d/1\